# Elasticsearch Realtime GET support

Tags: elasticsearch

When I index a document in ES, I am trying to access the same document within in the refresh interval has passed and the search is not returning the result. Is there a Realtime GET support which allows to get a document once indexed regardless of the "refresh rate" of the index. I tried reducing the refresh_interval to 500ms instead of 1s, but my search query happens even before 500 ms and it is not a good idea to reduce it even further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After indexing a document, you can GET it immediately without waiting for the refresh interval.

The [GET API is real-time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#realtime)

So if you index a new document like this

```
POST index/type/1
{ "name": "John Doe" }
```

You can get it immediately without waiting using

```
GET index/type/1
```

If you search, however, you'll need to wait for the refresh interval to pass in order to retrieve the new document or call the refresh API.

For completeness' sake, it's worth stating that when indexing you also have the option of [refreshing the shards immediately](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-refresh), by passing the `refresh=true` parameter like below. Note, however, that this can have bad performance implications, so it should be used sparingly.

```
POST index/type/1?refresh=true
{ "name": "John Doe" }
```

Also worth noting that in ES 5, you'll have the option of telling ES to [wait for a refresh](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/docs-refresh.html) before returning from the create call:

```
POST index/type/1?refresh=wait_for
{ "name": "John Doe" }
```

In this case, once the POST request returns, you're guaranteed that the new document is available in the next search call.

Comment: For search you can force refresh using the refresh API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html