# Elasticsearch: Fetching results faster than update

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having have some Elasticsearch documents indexed and I am updating one of them (a minor change, such as updating the field `title` of the latter).

The issue is that as soon as I do this then I fetch all the documents - however, the document does not seem to have been updated yet.
Instead, if I resend the fetch request then I receive the updated data.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: This answer would probably help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795834/elasticsearch-realtime-get-support/38796173#38796173 + and this one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42406674/elastic-search-get-doesnt-give-latest-document/42407323#42407323

Comment: That actually helped alot, @Val! Thank you.